# how to draw arrow that looks like the symbol "\leadsto" in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

please refer to the answer of how to draw a process flow figure?
  Now I what to change all arrows look like  `\leadsto` in latex, you are refer to the picture
     [image]
  I can not find it in the manual, would someone know how to do it? Please help me.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}

    \tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm}}
    \tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm}}

    \tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth]
    \node[bag]{$(B)$} 
        child{ edge from parent node[right]{t}; \node[bag]{$(Rgood)$}
                child{ edge from parent node[right]{and}; \node[bag]{$(and)$}
                        child[missing]
                        child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{it}; \node[bag]{$(path1)$}}
                        child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{else}; \node[bag]{$(path2)$}}
                }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add option `edge from parent` to specify a style for the edges of the tree, and use decorations to get that "wavy" line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm}}
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,
    edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=3mm}}]
    \node[bag]{$(B)$}
        child{ edge from parent node[right]{t}; \node[bag]{$(Rgood)$}
            child{ edge from parent node[right]{and}; \node[bag]{$(and)$}
                child[missing]
                child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{it}; \node[bag]{$(path1)$}}
                child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{else}; \node[bag]{$(path2)$}}
        }};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: result]

Comment: thanks, however, what's wrong with my code, i add the style, but it doesn't work. Please refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67079/why-it-doesnt-take-effect-after-adding-edge-from-parent-style