# how to draw part of the picture to be line and the other part to be the "\leadsto" symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, tikz-trees

Please refer to the answer of [how to draw arrow that looks like the symbol "\leadsto" in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67056/how-to-draw-arrow-that-looks-like-the-symbol-leadsto-in-latex/67070#67070) in the picture all lines are changed to the `\leadsto`:

[image]

Now i want to keep the connector between "b" and "Rgood" be the line like"->", so how to change the code ? since the style `edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=3mm}}]` is for the whole picture.

Comment: Downvote: I don't think it is good to ask a chain of follow-up questions, each referring to the last one. This is not a forum thread, it is exhausting to dig all other questions up. I believe that questions are preferred, which can be understood by means of just their own description, whereas a reference might clarify some details or provide an interesting comparison. Also the title appears to not describe what is wanted here very precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the leadsto-like decoration into styles which allows you to manually apply them to exactly the arcs you want.

This version with the `edge from parent` preceeding the actual node is a bit of a hack to achieve the edge-labels.
The edge appears to be inserted again for the nodes, so i had to add `edge from parent[draw=none]` after each node.

Unless someone better knows an elegant solution that uses the tree library and its automatic growth, personally i would refrain from this and prefer placing the nodes and connecting them with edges manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm}}
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,
    leadsto/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=3mm}}]
    \node[bag]{$(B)$}
        child {edge from parent node[right]{t}; \node[bag]{$(Rgood)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
            child{ edge from parent[leadsto] node[right]{and}; \node[bag]{$(and)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
                child[missing]
                child{ edge from parent[leadsto] node[right=0.1cm]{it}; \node[bag]{$(path1)$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
                child{ edge from parent[leadsto] node[right=0.1cm]{else}; \node[bag]{$(path2)$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this result what you want?