# Stretchable \leadsto

Tags: arrows

I'd like something similar to `\xrightarrow` and `\xleftarrow` but for squigy arrows `\leadsto` in `LaTeX`. I need to do this because I sometimes have to overset the `\leadsto` with some equation/label that can be long. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This might give some ideas: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67056/how-to-draw-arrow-that-looks-like-the-symbol-leadsto-in-latex

Comment: thanks.. and can I use $ and $$ for actual LaTeX output of math types?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow

Comment: @Steven upped! perfect, I think thats the one! sorry if I couldnt find a way to search these duplicates here

Comment: I'm glad that seems to fit your need.  For better precision on the arrowheads, I would recommend replacing the `\!` with a tuned negative kern(e.g., `\kern-1.8pt` or whatever value works).